# Z-index hierarchy issue with sibling elements

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have two sibling elements one under the other and a `:before` block, which should be under the first one, but above the second one:

http://jsfiddle.net/fh6rj09n/

HTML:

```
<div class="foo-1"></div>
<div class="foo-2">
    <a href="#">Hover me</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.foo-1 {
    background-color: #333;
}
.foo-1:before {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px red;
    z-index: -1;
}
.foo-2 {
    background-color: #555;
    z-index: -2;
}
a {
    line-height: 100px;
    color: white;
}
```

The 2nd block also has an `a` element, which becomes unclickable, because overlapped by the `:before` block of the 1st element. What kind of z-index hierarchy should I apply to make the link clickable?

Comment: why do you use `top:50%`, should it be `top:0px`? http://jsfiddle.net/fh6rj09n/1/

Comment: Khanh TO, to show you the reason I want the :before block to be under the first container.

Comment: Your link is in `<div class="foo-2">` which is actually under the `foo-1`. How do you want it to be clickable?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Vlad, what HTML structure would you propose in this case?

Comment: do you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fh6rj09n/2/? but without the top border of the shadow

Comment: Khanh, that's correct.

Comment: this is like a hack, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/7f9p1aLp/ . I don't know how to do it better yet, investigating

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7f9p1aLp/1/

Comment: Thanks Khanh, I should have mentioned that the 1st container also has content which gets overlapped in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're setting negative `z-index` to elements in the same context as the `body` tag. This makes the `body`tag overlap the rest of nodes in the DOM.
[image: Try to access any node with the browser inspector, and you'll see what's happening.]